# How to extrapolate from fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

I have that,

$$f(x) = 1-(\frac{x^2}{\pi^2})$$ where it has period $2L = 2\pi$

I found that my Fourier series for $f(x)$ is 
$$\frac{2}{3} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{-4(-1)^n}{\pi^2 n^2}\cos(nx)$$
(1)

I am to find that,

$$\frac{\pi^2}{12} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$$ (2)

I have no idea how to proceed from this point onwards,

Trying parseval's identity yields me:

$$\frac{28}{48} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{16(-1)^{2n}}{\pi^4 n^4}$$
(3)

Which unless i made a mistake doesnt yield anything obvious to me. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What are you trying to find?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $f(x)$ equals its Fourier series?

Comment: using the Fourier series of f(x) deduce equation (2)

Comment: If you know $f(x)$ equals its Fourier series, just set $x=0.$